# asp.net copy gridview data to textboxes without postback (vb)

Tags: gridview, postback

I have a gridview in asp.net application,with data coming from a MySQL database.

Each gridview row has over 50 fields, most of which are hidden, so only 5 are actually displayed on the gridview.

When you click on any row, the data on all the columns of the row on the gridview, are copied to various textboxes below the gridview.

All works fine however it appears everytime I click on a row, there is a postback to the server, which makes the process of displaying the data below rather slow.

i would like to copy the data from each cell on the row of the gridview to the respective textbox directly, without further server intervention. Since all the data I need is on the gridview (just hidden), I don't see the point of having to check server everytime a row is clicked.

how can I copy the data to textboxes without having to do postbacks everytime ?

here is the code (part) I use to copy the data from gridview to textboxes:

```
         Protected Sub Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

             txtOD_OCC.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(17).Text.ToString()
             txtOC_OCC.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(18).Text.ToString()
        etc....

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you'd need to do this with client-side code instead of server-side code. Using JavaScript you would identify the elements you need (the element which contains the value and the element which should receive the value) and copy the value from one to the other. Or perhaps both elements can be pre-populated with the value and just shown/hidden accordingly. Note however that if you're going to be changing the behavior of the `GridView` like this then you're probably going to run into other problems with it. You may want to move to another grid mechanism entirely, such as jQuery DataTables.

Comment: @David, I agree Jquery Datatables would be a better option than using Gridview but, since I am a new comer to asp.net, I would prefer to see if I can manage first to do what I need within Visual Studio, without adding jquery etc.  You mention I can do this with client-side code/javascript...do you have an examples or links where I can see this ?? I've looked quite a lot on the net for this info but I didn't find anything that made sense.

Comment: Well, you say you want to learn on native controls first, but the very nature of your question is that the native control isn't what you want. If I'm being honest, using WebForms at all is likely going to result in a lot of unnecessary post-backs and unintuitive structures. If you use MVC instead then including DataTables (or something similar) is pretty natural and a lot closer to native functionality.

Comment: ok, I take it from your comment that then native gridview control doesn't have a way to do what I need on client-side, without going back to the server everytime. I assume that's why I don't find anything on the internet about it.  I appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Javascrip (in my sample JQuery) to get the values in Client and put it in Textboxes:

The gridView have a ID and an attribute ClientIDMode, wich cause that ID not change in Render:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdEmployees" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LastName" DataField="LastName"/>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Phone" DataField="Phone"/>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

After, add the next JQuery functionality:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grdEmployees tr").click(function () {
                $(this).find('td').each(function (e) {
                    alert($(this).text());
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This javascript Add an Event to the Click in "#grdEmployees tr" (when a TR -row- is clicked). When this event Fire, with javascript get each TD -column- in the gridview (render as table) and show the value.

Comment: this is what I was looking for....will do some search to make it work with my app. I appreciate the guidance.